# Stream Chromecast Desktop with shortcut

Tags: windows-10, chromecast

I'd like to be able to initiate "Cast my desktop" from a desktop shortcut / keystroke on a windows 10 box.
The recipient is a Samsung UN55FH6030 TV with a Chromecast attached.
(The chromecast is stock / not rooted and I assume first gen).

The ideal situation would be to treat the television itself as a secondary display (Win10 -> Samsung), though that seems unlikely.
The most approachable solution is to just trigger Chrome's "Cast my desktop" function (I suppose internally to Chromecast[0] or whatever).

All I've managed to do so far is use Chrome's configurable keyboard shortcuts to open the cast menu with a keystroke, but that doesn't put it in focus, and it doesn't allow for keyboard-based input.

It'd be great, at least, if I could put down a desktop shortcut to, maybe, chrome://extension-id/do-the-thing or something. If that's possible.

Anyone got any tips?

Comment: [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm familiar with ahk and could crank out a script, but I'm not sure what the "target" of it would be. It's possible to set up a macro to:
Switch to chrome, initiate the cast extension, perform a mouse move, click at a given offset.
But that assumes a given screen resolution and screws up if Chrome is, say, on Monitor 2 instead of Monitor 1. Doable if keyboard shortcuts in the popup menu were available, but to my knowledge they are not.